# Displaying properties in a horizontal, pleasant way

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, editor, unity-editor

I have two integer properties and want to display them in one line.

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(MazeConfiguration))]
public class MazeConfigurationEditor : Editor
{
    MazeConfiguration myTarget;

    public void OnEnable()
    {
        myTarget = (MazeConfiguration)target;
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {

        EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
        myTarget.Width = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Width", myTarget.Width);
        myTarget.Length = EditorGUILayout.IntField("Length", myTarget.Length);
        EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
    }
}
```

But it looks very wide.
[image]

And if I change width of the Inspector it looks like this
[image]

So I want to remove those big spaces between a label and its input field, and add some space between properties.

I heard that Property Drawer can help me so I tried it

```
public class MyIntAttribute : PropertyAttribute { }

    [CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(MyIntAttribute))]
    public class MyIntDrawer : PropertyDrawer
    {
        public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
        {
            EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

            // position = EditorGUI.PrefixLabel(position, GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive), label);

            var rect = new Rect(position.x / 2f, position.y, position.width / 2f, position.height);

            EditorGUI.PropertyField(rect, property);

            EditorGUI.EndProperty();
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't move an input field closer to a respective label, I can only change width of an input field.

How do I remove space between Label and Input field, and add space between different properties?

Answer (score 0):

All I needed is to change

```
EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth
```